# How to get last message from each conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the list of recent messages from friends of a user; just like messenger and Whatsapp.

I have 2 tables for this: users and chat tables

Users table

```
***user_id*** ***username*** ***photo*** ***status***

1                brada         a.png        offline

2                john          b.png        online

3                doe           c.png        offline


***chat table***

***id*** ***user_id*** ***friend_id*** ***message*** ***message_token*** ***msg_time***

1              2             1            hello              ababa           2013-08-21 03:24:00

2              1              2            hi                ababa            2013-08-21 03:24:00

3              1              3           hi man!             baba             2013-08-21 03:24:00

4              3              1           im good             baba             2013-08-21 03:24:00
```

I want the output to be like this for brada:
***friend_id*** ***username***  ***message*** ***photo*** ***status***

```
 2              john             hi          b.png        online

 3              doe              i'm good    c.png        offline
```

***I am findinf it hard to join the two tables. My code only pick the last messages: ***

`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id in (SELECT max(id) FROM chat WHERE (user_id ='1 OR friend_id =1) GROUP BY message_token )`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
SELECT c.chatid,
       u.USER_ID,
       u.username,
       f.USER_ID AS friend_id,
       f.username AS friend_name,
       c.meassage,
       c.msg_time
FROM chat c

inner join
(
            SELECT user_id,
                   friend_id,
                   MAX(msg_time) AS maxtime
            FROM chat
            GROUP BY user_id,
                     friend_id
        ) c2
            ON c2.user_id = c.user_id
               AND c.friend_id = c2.friend_id
               AND c.msg_time = c2.maxtime
    INNER JOIN users u
        ON c.user_id = u.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN users f
        ON f.USER_ID = c.friend_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1 --filtered for brada
```

Comment: it is only picking the last message from the sender; in this case Brada.

Comment: if you want the messages where Brada is the friend_id too? Do you have an example with different msg_times and the output that you would expect then. Why is your expected result chant nr 2 and 3 and not 1 and 3?

Comment: Let me clarify:  i want brada to get the last message of the conversation whether the sender is the receiver or brada himself.  For example: WhatsApp shows the last message as : if it's sent by brada it would be... You: hello; but if it's the receiver it will be... I'm good.

Answer (score 0):

- Getting required columns and creating rank for rows, rank is set with recent
- However since it is a timestamp one user_id can't have same time for two different messages and hence this should work

```
SELECT 
CHAT.FRIEND_ID,
USERS.USERNAME,
CHAT.MESSAGE,
USERS.PHOTO,
USERS.STATUS,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY CHAT.MSG_TIME DESC) AS RANK_

FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN  CHAT 
ON  USERS.USER_ID = CHAT.USER_ID
QUALIFY RANK_ = 1
```

if qualify doesn't work in your sql then create a cte:

```
with main_data as (

SELECT 
CHAT.FRIEND_ID,
USERS.USERNAME,
CHAT.MESSAGE,
USERS.PHOTO,
USERS.STATUS,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY CHAT.MSG_TIME DESC) AS RANK_

FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN  CHAT 
ON  USERS.USER_ID = CHAT.USER_ID
)

select * from main_data where rank_ = 1
```